# box-shadow not producing a box shadow around div

Tags: html, css

The following CSS does not produce any shadow effects around the div element.

```css
.someDivClass {
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.68);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.68);
}
```

```html
<div class="someDivClass">test</div>
```

Comment: `rgba` only accepts a max of 4 inputs, you have 5.

Answer (score 3):

It's because there is a zero too much in your rgb color, which is defined with three base colors: **R**ed, **G**reen and **B**lue. The fourth parameter is for opacity.

```css
.someDivClass {
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);
}
```

```html
<div class="someDivClass">test</div>
```